# Alterar uma div vinda de outro site com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Quero alterar uma div vinda de outro site com JavaScript, é possível? No caso eu queria alterar apenas o link de uma imagem dessa div.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como é seu código? O que já tentou? Poste teu código e a div que está vindo

Comment: @DaviYals, será muito mais fácil de lhe ajudar se você postar o código que você desenvolveu para criar sua `div` e não a imagem, pois assim podemos alterar o mesmo mais facilmente

Comment: http://filmes.xxxilha.com/the-flash/ selecione o player e selecione o episódio, vc verá então a logo que eu quero alterar vinda de outro servidor